# Ternary Operator alternatives for more than 2 values

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my react-native applications, i had written a code like this.

```
   return (  
            <PersonHandler
                profilePicture={item.user.profileImage ? {uri: item.user.profileImage} : DefaultUser}
                firstName={item.user.firstName}
                lastName={item.user.lastName}

                buttonBorderColor={item.status === 0 ? "#000000" : "#37CAFA"}
                buttonBackgroundColor={item.status === 0 ? null : "#37CAFA"}
                buttonTextColor={item.status === 0 ? "#000000" : "#FFFFFF"}          
                buttonText={item.status === 0 ? USER_STATUS.REQUESTED : USER_STATUS.FOLLOWING}

                submitting={unfollowIsInProgress && item._id === unfollowingPerson._id}
                onButtonPress={() => this.onUnfollowPress(item)}
            />
        );
```

Now I have more than 2 statuses to handle, so the ternary operator here cannot be used. What will be the best approach to handle a situation like this?

I have 3 statuses now. 0, 1 and 2. According to the status I have to handle the following conditions.

```
 buttonBorderColor={item.status === 0 ? "#000000" : "#37CAFA"}
                buttonBackgroundColor={item.status === 0 ? null : "#37CAFA"}
                buttonTextColor={item.status === 0 ? "#000000" : "#FFFFFF"}          
                buttonText={item.status === 0 ? USER_STATUS.REQUESTED : USER_STATUS.FOLLOWING}
```

Comment: You can use if else ladder or switch case for this purpose

Comment: You know you can write `item.status === 0 ? A : (item.status === 1 ? B : C)` right?

Comment: Nested ternaries are great. Read this stuff from Eric Elliot - https://medium.com/javascript-scene/nested-ternaries-are-great-361bddd0f340

Comment: Move stuff out of the damn view

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure you can use the ternary operator still, you just have to use it *twice*, for example:

```
 buttonBorderColor={
   item.status === 0
     ? "#000000"
     : item.status === 1
       ? "#37CAFA"
       : "#FFFFFF" // if status is 2
}
```

That said, it's a bit uncomfortable to read - you might consider using an array indexed by `status` whose value is the color you want instead:

```
const colors = ["#000000", "#37CAFA", "#FFFFFF"]
// ...
buttonBorderColor={ colors[item.status] }
```

Comment: All the answers would have solved the problem. But I think use of an array would be the most appropriate one. I achieved this through 3 arrays. Thanks CertainPerformance.

Comment: @Shashika You could also have one array with an options object for each status.

Answer (score 2):

Use `switch` to handle three statuses. Nesting `ternary` operators is not a wise practice.

```
var buttonBorderColor,
  buttonBackgroundColor,
  buttonTextColor,
  buttonText

switch (item.code) {
  case 0:
    buttonBorderColor = '#000000'
    buttonBackgroundColor = null
    buttonTextColor = "#000000"
    buttonText = USER_STATUS.REQUESTED
    break;
  case 1:
    buttonBorderColor = '#37CAFA'
    buttonBackgroundColor = '#37CAFA'
    buttonTextColor = "#FFFFFF"
    buttonText = USER_STATUS.FOLLOWING
    break;
  case 2:
    buttonBorderColor = '#FFFFFF'
    buttonBackgroundColor = '#FFFFFF'
    buttonTextColor = "#FFFFFF"
    buttonText = USER_STATUS.ELSE
    break;
  default:
    break;
}
```

Comment: "*Nesting ternary operators is not a wise practice*" - why do you think that?

Comment: @JollyJoker Ternary's are easier to read if formatted correctly imo - similar to a switch statement. The issue is not many people format them properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way

```
buttonBorderColor={item.status === 0 ? "#000000" : (item.status === 1 ? "#000001" : "#37CAFA")}
```

or you can use if else ladder

```
if (item.status === 0) {
    buttonBorderColor = '#000000'
    buttonBackgroundColor = null
    buttonTextColor = "#000000"
    buttonText = USER_STATUS.REQUESTED
} else if (item.status === 1) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
const pickValue = (status, v1, v2, v3) => 
    status === 0
        ? v1
        : status === 1 
            ? v2
            : v3;

return (
    <PersonHandler
        profilePicture={item.user.profileImage ? { uri: item.user.profileImage } : DefaultUser}
        firstName={item.user.firstName}
        lastName={item.user.lastName}

        buttonBorderColor={pickValue(item.status, "#000000", "#37CAFA", null)}
        buttonBackgroundColor={pickValue(item.status, null, "#37CAFA", null)}
        buttonTextColor={pickValue(item.status, "#000000", "#FFFFFF", null)}
        buttonText={pickValue(item.status, USER_STATUS.REQUESTED, USER_STATUS.FOLLOWING, null)}

        submitting={unfollowIsInProgress && item._id === unfollowingPerson._id}
        onButtonPress={() => this.onUnfollowPress(item)}
    />
);
```